# How to construct a Turing machine for a language

Tags: turing-machines

I have proved that language $L$ is not regular and think that it is recognizable by a Turing machine. I want to prove it by constructing a Turing machine for it.

$L=\{0^n|n \in A\}$
where $A$ is set of all numbers that do not contain 1 in their base 3 representation. However, n is in base 10.

What I have done so far:
When I was proving that the language is not regular, I used the fact that there cannot be any arithmetic sequences in $A$. I think if I work on the number of 1 in base three, I may get somewhere.

Comment: If it is recognizable at all, it is recognizable by some Turing machine, so you're not proving anything. On the other hand, if it is context-free, you might want to prove it is, i.e., recognizable by a pushdown automaton.

Answer (score 4):

Try to come up with an algorithm, and then write the simplest possible program in some usual programming language for recognizing L. Then translate that program to a Turing machine.

N is not "in base 10" - it's just a number in your computer's memory, which is probably internally represented in base 2, but your program shouldn't care.

To check if a number contains 1 in base 3 representation, try to build the base-3 representation using the usual base conversion algorithm (digit = x mod 3, proceed with x div 3), and stop when you see a 1.

Comment: you mean for input 12, I have to first write 12 on tape. then convert it to base 3 and if I encountered 1, then reject ?

Comment: The original problem statement is, AFAIU, to write a recognizer. So the tape should initially contain a number of repetitions of the "0" character. For 12, it'd be 000000000000.

Answer (score 1):

As remarked already by jkff, a number is a number in whatever
representation. Actually you get your number $n$ in unary
representation as a sequence of $n$ $0$'s.

Checking whether the base 3 representation includes a $1$ is extremely
easy. You scan the input, and for every three $0$'s, you replace each
of the last two by a $+$ (just some symbol). This is like dividing by
3. When you reach the end, if there has been only a single $0$ read
since the last replacement, you reject the input, else you replace
each of the remainig $0$'s, if any, by $+$. Then you repeat a new scan, until
you have less than three $0$'s left. If there is only one $0$ left then the
input string is rejected, else it is accepted.

This is easily implemented with a Linear Bounded Automaton
(LBA). Hence the language is Context Sensitive (but that does not usually say
much more than recognizing it with a terminating Turing Machine).
It is probably not too hard to write a CS grammar for it.